# Does fstream::flush() or fstream::sync() guarantee the data have been written to the disk?

Tags: c++, buffer, fstream, disk, ofstream

I'm writing a mini database by using C++. In log module, I use `fstream` to append data to log file and I need data to be immediately written to disk. In http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/, I find

> When the buffer is flushed, all the data contained in it is written to the physical medium.

But in http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/7343/

> I've tried the flush() call, but that just flushes the program's buffers out into the file system's buffers, and does not guarantee that the data is physically written to disk.

I'm confused if the flush() or sync() call guarantee the data has been written to the disk, for example

```
std::fstream file;
file.open("...", std::ios::out | std::ios::app); // open a file
file << "..."; //append log
file.flush(); //or file.sync()
//file.flush() has returned
//system crashed(not only program crashed) or an interruption in the supply of electricity heppened
```

then when I restart the computer, whether the log is lost? If log will lost, does `fstream` have any way to force data write to the disk?

Comment: None of the standard C++ file I/O functions can guarantee you that data has actually be written to a physical medium, especially in a platform-independent manner. On any (driver) level between the application and the hardware, there still might be an intermediate buffer.

Comment: @Jodocus Thanks a lot! It means the only way to do it is using system call like fdatasync() ?

Comment: Yes, this might work. It goes without saying that this is plattform-dependent, though.

Comment: @Jodocus Although this question is old, why not rewrite your comments as an "answer"? (perhaps including a link to some source that backs it up). Your answer-in-comment was useful for me, and would have been more easily found as an actual answer...